# Datatables Serverside Processing with Column Filterting using Multiple Tables

Tags: php, datatables

I'm displaying a record set using `Datatables` pulling records from two tables.

#### Table A

```
sno      | item_id | start_date | end_date   | created_on |
===========================================================
10523563 | 2       | 2013-10-24 | 2013-10-27 | 2013-01-22 |
10535677 | 25      | 2013-11-18 | 2013-11-29 | 2013-01-22 |
10587723 | 11      | 2013-05-04 | 2013-05-24 | 2013-01-22 |
10598734 | 5       | 2013-06-14 | 2013-06-22 | 2013-01-22 |
```

#### Table B

```
id       | item_name                |
=====================================
2        | Timesheet testing        |
25       | Vigour                   |
11       | Fabwash                  |
5        | Cruise                   |
```

Now since the number of records returned is going to turn into a big number in near future, I want the processing to be done serverside. I've successfully managed to achieve that but it came at a cost. I'm running into a problem while dealing with filters.

[image: datables]

From the figure above, (1) is the column whose value will be in `int` (`item_id`), but using some small modifications inside the `while` loop of the mysql resource, I'm displaying the corresponding `string` using `Table B`.

Now if I use the filter (2), it is working fine since those values come from `Table A`

#### The Problem

When I try to filter from the field (3), if I enter a `string` value such as `fab` it says no record found. But if I enter an `int` such as `11` I get a single row which contains `Fabwash` as the item name.

So while filtering I'm required to use the direct value used in `Table A` and not its corresponding `string` value stored in `Table B`. I hope the point that I'm putting across is understandable because it is hard to explain it in words.

I'm clueless on how to solve the issue.

Comment: You should post the code sample that does this column altering. I gues you do that client side? In case you use Ajax, its better to do all processing serverside. That way you can easily change column behaviour without have to change both parts of the code.